# Why can't I connect to the tor network?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, network-configuration

I can't connect the tor network since a few weeks ago. It always worked fine but when I want to connect to the tor network my internet connection stops working or it says on the main page of tor that I'm not connected to the tor network. 
What I did noticed is that my internet stops working when I turn on that vpn mode for my apps.
But when I don't turn that modus on I can't connect to the tor network.

Comment: Which apps and which vpn mode are you talking about ?